# AnimatedBuilder being called multiple times

Tags: flutter

I have following codes. `newList` contains data fetched from `snapshot`.

```
Widget _buildListChild(AsyncSnapshot<ModelHolidays> snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.data.d;
    newList = json.decode(data.getholidaylist);

    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: size.getSizePx(10)),
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: newList.length,
        controller: scrollContainer,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final int count = 1; 
          final Animation<double> animation =
              Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 1.0).animate(
            CurvedAnimation(
              parent: holidayAnimationController,
              curve: Interval((1 / count) * index * 2, 1.0,
                  curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
            ),
          );

          holidayAnimationController.forward();

          return AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: holidayAnimationController,
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              print("######################");
              print("Animated Builder");
              print("######################");
              return Container();

            },
          );
        });
  }
```

**Problem**

The `newList` has only one record returned from API. But `AnimatedBuilder` seem to have some issue. The print statements inside `builder` of `AnimatedBuilder`, are printed multiple times infact 70+ times. Is this normal? If not how to fix it? I am fairly new in flutter.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the call to _buildListChild()? Are you working inside a StatefulWidget o Stateless?

Comment: @encubos its called in Streambuilder in build method. Its stateful

Comment: Well I am not sure, but I think the problem is not related with the AnimatedBuilder itself, but with your async call and the streambuilder.